# Graceful shutdown of the ws server

Tags: go, websocket, server

My websocket server is now just a waitgroup waiting for the connections to close. I would like it to work as in net/http Shutdown. There, the function knocks every certain time (by the way, why random) to close connections that do nothing. How does checking that the connection is not doing anything work? How to implement this in a websocket?

This a part of net/http Shutdown

```
    pollIntervalBase := time.Millisecond
  nextPollInterval := func() time.Duration {
    // Add 10% jitter.
    interval := pollIntervalBase + time.Duration(rand.Intn(int(pollIntervalBase/10)))
    // Double and clamp for next time.
    pollIntervalBase *= 2
    if pollIntervalBase > shutdownPollIntervalMax {
      pollIntervalBase = shutdownPollIntervalMax
    }
    return interval
  }

  timer := time.NewTimer(nextPollInterval())
  defer timer.Stop()
  for {
    if srv.closeIdleConns() && srv.numListeners() == 0 {
      return lnerr
    }
    select {
    case <-ctx.Done():
      return ctx.Err()
    case <-timer.C:
      timer.Reset(nextPollInterval())
    }
  }
```

This is closeIdleConns net/http

```
// closeIdleConns closes all idle connections and reports whether the
// server is quiescent.
func (s *Server) closeIdleConns() bool {
  s.mu.Lock()
  defer s.mu.Unlock()
  quiescent := true
  for c := range s.activeConn {
    st, unixSec := c.getState()
    // Issue 22682: treat StateNew connections as if
    // they're idle if we haven't read the first request's
    // header in over 5 seconds.
    if st == StateNew && unixSec < time.Now().Unix()-5 {
      st = StateIdle
    }
    if st != StateIdle || unixSec == 0 {
      // Assume unixSec == 0 means it's a very new
      // connection, without state set yet.
      quiescent = false
      continue
    }
    c.rwc.Close()
    delete(s.activeConn, c)
  }
  return quiescent
}
```

Comment: The process used for normal HTTP connections will not work for websockets, because regular HTTP connections are transactional and websockets are just sockets.

Comment: is there any way to implement this?

Comment: "Graceful" for a websocket connection is extremely application-dependent; you'll need to figure out at what point you can safely terminate a connection based on how you're using it and what the client expects.

Comment: If you have control over creating the frames as per RFC6455, just send a frame with opcode `ping`. This must be answered by a `pong`  frame from the client. If this will not happen in a given time close this connection.